# How this ReactJS syntax works?

Tags: javascript

I see the following kinda code for state management in the latest Hook Based component syntax in ReactJS.

```
const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");
```

What is this syntax called? And how does `React.useState()` creates and stores values in `input` and `setInput()` in local context?

Comment: Refer - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: What the code basically does is `const state = React.useState(""); const input = state[0]; const setInput = state[1]` The destructuring assignment eliminates the need for the temp variable state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `React.useState()` method is returning an `array` with two values:
The first value is the state itself (in your case an empty string).
The second value is a method to change the state.
The reason we use the square brackets on the left side is to set these to values meaningful name in a succinct way.
JavaScript allows us to get value from array in this way. Alternatively you could have written: `const myArr = React.useState("")` and then `const input = myArr[0]` and `const setInput = myArr[0]`
This way of getting the values out of an array is called array destructuring

Answer (score 0):

It's called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 0):

This is called array destructuring. You can find more info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment